# How can I more efficiently create a unique or incremental name within this bash for loop?

Tags: bash, for-loop, while-loop, iptables

The code below runs as a cronjob to retrieve and save a list of IPs, split the file in 2, and load each of the 2 files into 2 ipsets. The list is split because it's more than 65,535 lines. The code works, but it's ugly and I'd appreciate some feedback on how to make it better/cleaner/faster.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
curl -s "https://example.com/files/list.ipset" > /tmp/ipset.txt
TOTAL_LINES=$(wc -l </tmp/ipset.txt)
((LINES_PER_FILE=(TOTAL_LINES+2-1)/2))
split --lines=${LINES_PER_FILE} /tmp/ipset.txt /tmp/setsplit.
for f in /tmp/setsplit.*; do
        x="$(echo $f | sed 's/\/tmp\/setsplit\.//g')"
        iptables -t mangle -D PREROUTING -m set --match-set "$x" src,dst -j DROP
        ipset destroy "$x"
        ipset create "$x" hash:ip
        while read LINE; do ipset add "$x" $LINE; done < "$f"
        iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -m set --match-set "$x" src,dst -j DROP
done
rm -rf /tmp/setsplit.* /tmp/ipset.txt
```

My primary concern is the way variable x is created. Split creates the following files, which the for loop iterates:

/tmp/setsplit.aa

/tmp/setsplit.ab

Is there a better way to use the "aa" and "ab" portion of $f for the ipset name instead of using echo/sed to create variable x? Or even better, a base-name with a number increment, say: ipset destroy ListX where X is a unique number for each file processed by the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "$f"
/tmp/setsplit.aa
$ echo "${f##*.}"
aa
```

The `##` operator removes the longest prefix matching `*.` (i.e., everything up to and including the final `.`) from the expansion of `f`.

Answer (score 0):

@chepner shows the "right" way to get the suffix of `f`:

```
x=${f##*.}
```

This can be found in the "Parameter Expansion" section of the `bash` `man` page.

As for your other question, Yes the split command can produce a numbered sequence instead of lettered. That's on the `split` `man` page. Option `-d`. You can also change the size of the suffix, option `-a`.

I don't think the slowdown is from any of this though.